# Delete multiple records in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, get, routes

To remove only one record I realize this ajax

```
var borrar = confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminarlo?");
          if (borrar) 
          {
            var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
            $.ajax({
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                dataType: "json",
                data: {radicado: radicado},
                url:   ip+'/eliminarRadicado/delete/'+radicado,
                type:  'get',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    },
                success: function(respuesta){
                    alert(respuesta);
                },
                error: function(xhr,err){ 
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
          }
```

which sends by $get the id of the record that I delete the file and run this route :

```
Route::get('eliminarRadicado/delete/{id}', 'RadicadoController@destroy');
```

which ultimately goes to the driver and performs the function of removing

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    \App\Radicado::destroy($id);
    return response()->json(['Documento eliminado']);
}
```

What is not like removing more than one record (id ) I send. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't send delete requests using a `GET` verb. Instead you should use the `DELETE` verb which is semantically correct.

---

With your current approach, sending the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header doesn't do anything, as Laravel doesn't check the CSRF token for read requests (`GET` and `HEAD`). Instead you should pass all the IDs you want to deleted as parameters with a `DELETE` request like so:

```
var ids = [1, 10, 17]; // Use your own logic to set the array of the IDs here

$.ajax({
    headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token },
    dataType: "json",
    data    : { ids: ids },                   // Pass IDs array
    url     : ip + '/eliminarRadicado/delete',
    type    : 'delete',                       // Send a delete request

    beforeSend: function () {
    },

    success: function (respuesta) {
        alert(respuesta);
    },

    error: function (xhr, err) { 
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Then change your route definition to this:

```
Route::delete('eliminarRadicado/delete', 'RadicadoController@destroy');
```

And in your `destroy` controller method use the array of IDs received via the request:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    \App\Radicado::destroy($request->input('ids'));

    return response()->json(['Documento eliminado']);
}
```

Now you can pass an array of one or more IDs to be deleted using the same request.